# When is kinetic energy linear?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation, friction, work

If we were to plot kinetic energy and time, what would the circumstances be in order for kinetic energy to increase or decrease linearly?

The question I had in class showed a body with some velocity and some retarding friction force. The kinetic energy decreased linearly. Is this because the amount of energy converted to heat energy by friction is constant because the frictional force is constant?

Comment: It would help if you would post the exact question you saw in your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, kinetic energy will decrease linearly if friction is constant.

When there is a force, it does some work on the object that causes its energy to decrease linearly.

A constant force doing work only causes the **total** mechanical energy to decrease linearly, it doesn't cause the kinetic energy to decrease linearly with displacement.

However, in this case, there is no change in the potential energy of the body, hence the kinetic energy decreases linearly with displacement.

So yes, for the example you did in class, it's possible for kinetic energy to decrease linearly with displacement.

However, for it to decrease linearly with time, your change in kinetic energy must be constant.

Using calculus here,

d^2/dt^2 mv^2/2 = 0

d/dt m/2 * (va + va) = 0

d/dt mva = 0

m(a^2 + v da/dt) = 0

ma^2 + v * jerk = 0